# Ionic/Cordova App crashes on Windows Phone device but runs on emulator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

i have the following problem with my Cordova/Ionic App:

Android is working.
Also on Windows phone emulator the app works fine.  But on my Windows Phone Device the app crashes after retrieving some data from an AJAX request. The crash must by inside the *promise.resolve()* call after the successful ajax request, because the *doLogin().then()*-Function, which handles the promise-object, never gets called.

```
doLogin = function(){   
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     var request = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: HelperService.getPortalURL() + "login.action",
                data: loginData,
                dataType: 'json'
        });
        request.success(function (result) {
            if (result.message === "LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL") {
                $rootScope.currentUser.eanvDeviceToken=result.token;

                $rootScope.isOnline=true;
                deferred.resolve(result);

            } else if (result.message === "CREDENTIALS_INVALID") {
                $rootScope.isOnline=false;
                deferred.reject("Wrong credentials");
            }
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
        request.error(function (err) {

            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $rootScope.isOnline=false;
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
}
```

The Windows Phone dump files show the folowing exceptions:
0xC000005 - Access violation
and
0x8000003 - Breakpoint encountered

Comment: I have tested the app on a Windows Phone 10 device now - and it worked without any problems... So there is maybe an issue between windows phone 8.1 and Ionic?

Comment: Do you use [winstore-jscompat](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat)?

Comment: Yes I have included winstore-jscompat into index.html